# Outlook calendar script to look for date/time suggestions

Tags: vba, outlook, calendar

I know Outlook can suggest dates when planning a meeting. However, I would like to write more sophisticated scripts matching my exact requirements. For example: "Find the next available meeting date/time on a Tuesday or Thursday afternoon lasting three hours, where all obligatory participants and at least 50% of the optional participants and at least one of the specified rooms are available".

Is that possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

Call Recipient.FreeBusy or AddressEntry.GetFreeBusy to retrieve f/b data, then pick up the available slot.